# All-In-One vulnerability scanner for PHP project?

Tags: software-development, php, security, scanning

I've asked this on incorrect sub-site ([security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201016/can-we-anywhere-scan-projects-php-java-for-vulnerabilities-like-virustota)), however, i think that question fits this site more. So, I was searching for a tool, which includes multiple Vulnerability-Scanners, so we could upload a project (or even submit our website), and the tool scanned our site (or project) for Vulnerabilities.
But the difference is that, it scanned with multiple different scanners (like **VirusTotal**).

I've built the sketch of idea myself, to show what I mean:   http://allscanners.itask.software/

What should we do, when we need something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Bitbucket has a feature which is a bit like this, but the user interface is quite different from yours.

It is part of what they call "AutoDevops".

Once in a while (maybe each day), Bitbucket runs various vulnerability scanners on your code, for various programming languages. So your program can contain some JavaScript and some C#, AutoDevops will find the vulnerabilities for each language.

I don't think it analyzes your code very deeply. It just checks whether you are using libraries that have known vulnerabilities.

It is free.

Comment: Thanks for nice info! However, I am primarily focusing on PHP, because I work with CMS (like Wordpress and etc...) so, that method doesn't fit millions of users like me :(